# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Login with Facebook - PhP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, web, facebook-login

Just like the tittle say i have an error for a redirects loop in my page when tries to log in.

The test page is this:
[chichabusca.hol.es](http://chichabusca.hol.es)

I know that the problem is not in the settings app of facebook. And the app domain and site URL are well placed, and are respectively `chichabusca.hol.es` & `http://www.chichabusca.hol.es`.

but it failed to realize has the problem is, if anyone know or thought something, let me know

**index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Login with Facebook</title>
<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?>      <!--  After user login  -->
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
  <h1>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME']; ?></h1>
  <p>Welcome to "facebook login" tutorial</p>
  </div>
<div class="span4">
 <ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">Image</li>
    <li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture"></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook ID</li>
<li><?php echo  $_SESSION['FBID']; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook fullname</li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook Email</li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['EMAIL']; ?></li>
<div><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
</ul></div></div>
    <?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login --> 
<div class="container">
<h1>Login with Facebook</h1>
           Not Connected
<div>
      <a href="fbconfig.php">Login with Facebook</a></div>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**fbconfig.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require 'functions.php'; 
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('511159849023226','046cca8865571310071    5500b220c666c');
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://chichabusca.hol.es/fbconfig.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get     Facebook ID
    $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
/* ---- Session Variables -----*/
    $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
    $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
 //   checkuser($fuid,$ffname,$femail);
/* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code your loop is caused when your earlier code is failign but not being dealt with, the try catch blocks are preventing it from just dieing.  Your if session block at the bottom has basically become the catcher for the error but as it redirects back to login you hit an infinite loop and that loop is caught by max_redirects in php.ini

comment out the header in that else block while you diagnose the problem by echoing out those exceptions.

While debugging i would also add an exit so just do this inside the catch block.

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ex);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```